# Stuck on basics IOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

new to Ios can somebody explain why this works:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
vControler = [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

vControler ->mPortSIPSDK =mPortSIPSDK;
```

and this does not:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard =  [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

vControler = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"restorTest”];
vControler ->mPortSIPSDK =mPortSIPSDK;
```

all is good with the 2 part of code both logs of vControler.class return the same but calls to mPortSIPSDK does not work in the second case.

Comment: Post the compiler error message.

Comment: I think that you should give the main bundle of the app when getting the storyboard : [NSBundle mainBundle] but indeed what error do you get?

Comment: Hi Guys, dont get any errors just calls to mPortSIPSDK don't execute if 1 case all is OK, 2 case no execution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`

> This method creates a new instance of the specified view controller
>   each time you call it.

So your second method creates a *new* instance of the view controller,
and the first method returns the *existing* instance of the view controller
that is connected to the tab bar.

*Remark:* As @trojanfoe correctly commented, the preferred way is to declare `mPortSIPSDK` as
a `@property` (if you haven't done so yet) and then access the property (using the "dot-notation") instead of accessing the instance variable directly (with "->"):

```
vControler.mPortSIPSDK = mPortSIPSDK;
```

*Update:* As I understand it, you have the following problem: The `AppDelegate` has
an instance variable `mPortSIPSDK` (yes, it is an instance variable in the sample project that you got and I will not talk about instance variable vs properties here :-)
and in some view controller you need this variable. In the sample project, the
AppDelegate passes `mPortSIPSDK` to all view controllers of the tab bar controller.

You can do the same in your app: The AppDelegate passes `mPortSIPSDK` to the 
initial view controller(s). When you segue from one view controller to the next,
you pass `mPortSIPSDK` along to the next view controller (in `prepareForSegue`)
and so on.

An alternative way is that each view controller "fetches" `mPortSIPSDK` from the 
AppDelegate. That would require that you make `mPortSIPSDK` publicly accessible
(a `@property` or at least a `@public` instance variable).
But I actually prefer the first ("pass the baton") approach.

Comment: You might want to mention to him about accessing instance variables using the `->` operator as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :),so how can I get existing instance of the view controller in app delegate? and whats the deal with -> :)

Comment: @Waylli: Your first code example works correctly, why can't you use that? - (About "->": search for "objective c property vs instance variable", there are many opinions on that, but it is probably unrelated to your particular problem.)

Comment: @MartinR I want to use navigation VC and make custom segues and not to be limited to TabbarNavigation....

Comment: @Waylli: Perhaps you can be a bit more specific: What is `vController`? When and when do you set `vControler.mPortSIPSDK`? Perhaps `prepareForSegue` is what you are looking for?

Comment: @MartinR I am trying to make a VoIP app based on http://www.portsip.com/voipsdk.html in their sample code only case 1 is used and they use only VC's embedded in tabbarcontroler, I want to use other navigation and VC's that are not embeded in TBC. so vControler is # import "ViewControler.h" //@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,PortSIPEventDelegate>
{
    PortSIPSDK* mPortSIPSDK;
    ViewController *vControler;}  SORRY IF I AM VAGUE THIS IS MY FIRST QUESTION HERE :)

Comment: @Waylli: I have extended the answer and hope that it helps.

Comment: @MartinR, Thanks a millll, I got it working as you suggested :) how can I give you credit? (as mentioned before 1st question)

Answer (score 1):

Do like this, It will work

```
FirstViewController v1 = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];

SecViewController v2 = [[SecViewController alloc]init];

UITabBarController *tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

tabBar.viewControllers =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:v1,v2,nil];

self.window.rootViewController =tabBar;
```

Comment: How does this answer relate to the question?